# msgbox vb.net textarea equivalent

Tags: vb.net, msgbox

I want to output a long error (> 200 words) to a user of an vb.net admin app. The user should be able to copy the message and analyze it.  the msgbox function doesn't allow me to do that.  What would?

Comment: A `TextBox` would do the trick, no?

Comment: maybe try creating a small modal window or form and put your text inside. Or if you can use WPF check out the Popup Control, providing the functionality for some quick action.

Comment: Create a form with a `TextBox` with `ReadOnly` set to `True` and display it as a modal dialogue. The `ShowDialog` method will return the same `DialogResult` values that `MessageBox.Show` would, which you should be using rather than `MsgBox`.

Comment: Could you use the windows event logs?